# How do I use $or, $in and $size in together in a Ruby query in Mongo?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to write the following Mongo query in a complex query: `{$or:[ {field:{$in:[X]}} , {field:{$size:0}}]}`

Currently my query builder looks like this: https://gist.github.com/735099

Everything commented out is what I have tried and not been successful with.  The closest I was able to get was this `query[:dma_codes] = {'$or' => [{'dma_codes' => {'$in' => [@bid_request[:geo][:dma]]}},{'dma_codes' => { '$size' => 0}}] }`

I was still getting the following error:

```
Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for #<Mongo::OperationFailure: invalid operator: $or>>
Mongo::OperationFailure - invalid operator: $or:
```

Is there something I am missing about constructing this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
query['$or'] = [{'dma_codes' => {'$in' => [@bid_request[:geo][:dma]]}},{'dma_codes' => { '$size' => 0}}]
```

But I don't know ruby very well.